# Getting Information from Calendar and GMail in Android

Tags: android, gmail

Is there away to access your calendar in Gmail either through the web or the gmail app, or maybe the calendar app on the android? First i'm just trying to find out if this is possible. I'm trying to make a calendar app for practice.

Comment: Yes, I wrote an article about it http://jimblackler.net/blog/?p=151

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to use the [google-api-java-client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client) API to pull the data directly from the web services.  It is possible to access the calendar through the content provider on the phone, but since it's not part of the Android SDK, there's no guarantee that it will work on all devices (or that it will work on future versions of the platform).