# To display user name and details from google id and display them in my android app

Tags: android, google-api, gson, accountmanager

Actually iam developing an apllication through which i can sign through my google id and i have to display the name and pic of that googleid in my application.Iam succesfull in getting the google id stored in my android phone but now i want to display the details of that id in my application.Please help me with some sample code or application...

Comment: have a look at this...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5587043/getting-information-from-calendar-and-gmail-in-android